# Fatal error occurring in Javascript forming array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, fatal-error

I want to make a function that forms an array based on the user input so I write the javascript as below but it only returns a fatal error. What is wrong with this code? I try to match with the book's code but I don't find anything particularly different so I came to the StackOverflow. The code is as follows

```
function arrayForm(start, limit)
{
let array = [];
for (start <= limit; start++;)
{
    array.push(start);
}
    return array;
}

console.log(arrayForm(1,10));
```

Comment: What _"fatal error"_? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have a look at how a `for` works. `(start <= limit; start++;)` is not correct.

Comment: I found this problem is caused by using function parameter "start" directly at for loops and it is solved by using i = start; and changed to i in for loops. Now, I would like to ask why using parameter directly at the for loops cause fatal error? or is this error happens by not using for loops properly?

Comment: _"why using parameter directly at the for loops cause fatal error?"_ - This has nothing to do with the parameter. You're just not using `for` correctly... `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, it solved and it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
{
let array = [];
for (let i = start; i <= limit; i++)
{
    array.push(i);
}
    return array;
}

console.log(arrayForm(1,10));
```